# How to abort a declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying the new declarative pipeline syntax.

I wonder, how can I abort all the stages and steps of a pipeline, when for example a parameter has an invalid value.

I could add a `when` clause to every stage, but this isn't optimal for me.  Is there a better way to do so?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work fine with a [`when`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) directive, if you make use of the [`error`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-error-code-error-signal) step.

For example, you could do an up-front check and abort the build if the given parameter value is not acceptable — preventing subsequent stages from running:

```java
pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    string(name: 'targetEnv',
           defaultValue: 'dev',
           description: 'Must be "dev", "qa", or "staging"')
  }
  stages {
    stage('Validate parameters') {
      when {
        expression {
          // Only run this stage if the targetEnv is invalid
          !['dev', 'qa', 'staging'].contains(params.targetEnv)
        }
      }
      steps {
        // Abort the build, skipping subsequent stages
        error("Invalid target environment: ${params.targetEnv}")
      }
    }
    stage('Checkout') {
      steps {
        echo 'Checking out source code...'
      }
    }
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        echo 'Building...'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to stop proceeding to next stage with result 'Success'

Comment: @Deepaklal you cann use `script {currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'}` before the error step

Comment: I also think you shoudl set the result to error to stop next stages from executing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `FlowInterruptedException`, e.g.:

```
import hudson.model.Result
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException

pipeline {
  ...
  steps {
    script {
      throw new FlowInterruptedException(Result.ABORTED)
    }
  ...
}
```

This will stop execution immediately like the `error` step, but with more control over the result.

Please note that it requires you to **approve a signature**:

```
new org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException hudson.model.Result
```

Apart from `Result.ABORTED` there's also: `Result.SUCCESS`, `Result.UNSTABLE`, `Result.FAILURE` and `Result.NOT_BUILT`.

**Disclaimer**: it's a bit of a hack.

Comment: I used "currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'"  and then error to achieve an abort without using internal Jenkins knowledge.